How to authenticate GitHub REST API in Azure on behalf of Azure Pipelines GitHub App?
I am trying to make a GitHub PR from my Azure Pipeline. I already have Azure Pipeline GitHub App installed. That's how my Azure Pipeline connects to the GitHub repository. It already has the permission to make PR. So I guess I only need to somehow know the token and use it to make the GitHub API request. Is it possible? How can I do it?

Hi @Ingun전인건, you can create a GitHub service connection and use AzurePipelines for OAuth Configuration. When you run GitHub API, it will use the token from the service connection.

I haven't found a way to get the token directly from the Azure Pipeline GitHub App.
As a workaround, you can create a GitHub service connection and use AzurePipelines for OAuth Configuration. Then call GitHub REST API using this service connection in the third-party extension Github AzureDevOps Rest Api Integration.

Create a GitHub service connection


Authentication method: Grant authorization
OAuth Configuration: AzurePipelines
Click Authorize to finish the authentication with your Github
Assign the service connection a Service connection name and Save.


Install the third party extension Github AzureDevOps Rest Api Integration into your Azure DevOps organization.

Use the extension to call GitHub REST API


- task: azuredevopsgithub@0
  inputs:
    gitHubConnection: '{The GitHub service connection you created}'
    method: 'POST'
    body: |
      {
        "title": "Merging changes from branch1 to main",
        "head": "refs/heads/branch1",
        "base": "refs/heads/main",
        "body": "Test creating PR in Azure pipeline"
      }
    githubrestapiurl: 'https://api.github.com/repos/{GitHubOwner}/{Repo}/pulls'


Result:



